# Typescript: infer type of Array item

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a interface which is imported from another file (I don't control this file), it has a property which is an array. I would like to get the type of the array item to use in my file. The type of the array item is not separately exported from the file.

```
// file1
interface TestInterface {
  items: Array<{ p1: string, p2: number }>
}

export type { TestInterface };


// file2
import { TestInterface } from './file1';

function operateOnArrayItem(item) {
 ...
}
```

this function expects an array item type. I am able to infer the type of the Array using something like: `TestInterface['items']`. Is there a way to infer the type of the Array item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work fine, if you access the nested type via the main type that you imported. The TypeScript documentation calls this an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
interface TestInterface {
  items: Array<{ p1: string, p2: number }>
}

function operateOnArrayItem(item: TestInterface['items'][number]) {
  // ...
}
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gJLmvJZAbwFgAoZZYSAWwwC5kBBKKOATwB4jkAHARkZYooAOYAaPgCZGIAK40ARtGQBfAHzlV5cjDkgEYYAHsQyY72hxIAeRAs27bLQAU1CDUbosuSLEQQANoA5O50wQC6gfJK0BEAlMTklAD0KcgAdFlaQA)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can have a util

```js
type ArrayElementType<ArrType> =
    ArrType extends readonly (infer ElementType)[] ? ElementType : never;
```

and use it wherever needed

```js
type TArrayEl = ArrayElementType<TestInterface['items']>;
```

[image]